# Which bridge should I use to transfer stable coin in other chain for solo chain?

Tags: token, bridge, solo-chain

My purpose is to transfer stable coin BUSD (BEP20) / USN (NEAR) / USDT (TRC20) to the other wallet address on the target BEP20, NEAR, TRC20 network

Is there any existing bridge that already supports it or do I need to build one?